# Splice array type prop in Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my component I have an array type of prop. If I use splice function on the array the $emit event doesn't fired. Could anybody help me why?
The removeItem method called by @click on button.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAwgx.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`splice` won't trigger the `set` on a `computed`. The easiest thing to do is to do an assignment to itself afterwards.

```
this.customBenefitsObj = this.customBenefitsObj;
```

See the demo below, which only writes "Test" once.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  computed: {
    test: {
      get() {
        return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
      },
      set(v) {
        console.log("Test");
      }
    }

  },
  mounted() {
    this.test.splice(0, 1);
    this.test = this.test;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By calling `splice` you modify a content of `customBenefitsObj` but not an array itself. If you do something like this:

```
this.customBenefitsObj = []
```

then customBenefitsObj's `set` will be called and `emit` as well.

Also it's not recommended to mutate a prop. You should emit a modified copy of an array and overwrite it in a parent component OR emit a remove operation and an element to remove (an actual remove also should be in a parent component).